# I need to switch images onlcick using JS

Tags: javascript, onclick

Firstly sorry if this seem a dumb question but I am learning javascript so may have messed this up.

I have an image that clickis replaced by nother image in its place.The problem I am trying to worj out is where do i place the second image link.

HTML below

```
 <div class="col-lg-3">

<img id="pbook" onclick="imageChange" class="imagebooks"  src="images/pink1.jpg" alt="">


 </div>
```

Javascript incomplete below:

```
function imageChange (newImage) {

 var secondImage= document.getElementById("pbook");
  secondImage.style.src = newImage;


}
```

Thank you for your kind help.

I have tried to create a function that when the image is click by the user is switches to another image. Basically the front image of a book that is then clicked on shows thw bck of the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right. You need to store the in-active image source somewhere:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <img id="pbook" class="imagebooks" src="images/pink1.jpg" data-src="images/pink2.jpg">
</div>
```

You'll be able to access the `data-src` through `dataset` in javascript, and thus, simultaneously store the in-active image.

```js
const image = document.getElementById("pbook");

image.onclick = () => {
    const newImage = image.dataset.src;

    image.dataset.src = image.src;
    image.src = newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code,
you might want to change the html and javascript a little bit.

- HTML :

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <img id="pbook" onclick="imageChange()" class="imagebooks" src="images/pink1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

- Java Script:

```js
function imageChange() {
  var secondImage = document.getElementById("pbook");
  secondImage.src = "images/secondImage.jpg"; // Replace "images/secondImage.jpg" with the path to your second image
}
```

*I HOPE IT HELPS*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<main>
<img src="#" alt="image" onclick='imageChange()'>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick='imageChange()'>OnClick</button>
</main>

<script>
function imageChange(){
document.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src','https://www.ridgedesign.ie/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Ridge-Design-Excellent-Customer-Service-1.png');
}
</script>
```